# How to use asynchronous right?

Tags: sql-server, angular, asp.net-web-api

I`m currently working on a project with Angular 8 and a web-API using a SQL server database.
I tried several times to update the status of a customer 
(status 0 == waiting customer, status 1 == current customer, status 2 == finished customer).  The put method works fine but after I change the status of a customer, I want to get the updated customer list (where status == 0).
If I use the http put method, then the http get method, it doesn't change my list.  However, if I make it an async function and add a small delay (await delay (50)) it works just fine.
Is that the expected behavior?

example:

```
NewCustomer() {
    (async () => {

      if (this.currentCustomer == null) {
        this.http.post("https://localhost:44342/api/customer", { "Status": 1 }).toPromise();
        await delay(50);
        this.GetCurrentCustomer();
        this.GetAvailableOrderID();
        await delay(50);
        this.Reset();
      }
```

Comment: Why are you using the `await` keyword on the `delay` and not on `this.http.post("https://localhost:44342/api/customer", { "Status": 1 })` ?

Comment: you don't do anything with your promise.  remove the awaits and add a .then to perform the actions you want after the web service call.

Answer (score 0):

use Observable instead of promise

```
NewCustomer(){
  if (this.currentCustomer == null){
    this.http.post("https://localhost:44342/api/customer", { "Status": 1 }).subscribe(result=>{
      this.GetCurrentCustomer();
      this.GetAvailableOrderID();
 })
}
}
```